# Can no longer mount ecryptfs after fsck removed Private.sig file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ecryptfs

OS: Ubuntu Server 18.04

I have an encrypted home directory. Recently I installed a Steam game that was writing to this directory (since Steam saves gamefiles to your home dir), and I think it started to have issues over time. I had to run fsck to fix some of the issues on the filesystem, and rebooted and everything was great. However, I did this again after encountering the same issue and now I can no longer mount my home directory.

Output of `$ ecryptfs-mount-private`

```
ERROR: Encrypted private directory is not setup properly
```

Output of `$ ecryptfs-recover-private .Private`

```
user@machine:~$ sudo ecryptfs-recover-private
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
INFO: Found [/home/.ecryptfs/user/.Private].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: Y
INFO: Found your wrapped-passphrase
Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n] Y
INFO: Enter your LOGIN passphrase...
Passphrase:
Inserted auth tok with sig [89b584e3b911c2dd] into the user session keyring
sed: can't read /home/.ecryptfs/user/.Private/../.ecryptfs/Private.sig: No such file or directory
```

And well yes, it appears my signature file is missing. Is there any recourse?

Edit: Posted on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200038/can-no-longer-mount-ecryptfs-after-fsck-removed-private-sig-file)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in Linux mint 19.3. 
This article partially helped me

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285541/mount-no-such-file-or-directory-with-encrypted-recovery

but with other steps.

### 1. Find the Passphrase

Replace USER with your user folder. Replace USERPASSWORD with your session user password.

```
# ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase /home/.ecryptfs/USER/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
Passphrase: USERPASSWORD
54b86496d376242f0bef16886a1a2218
```

### 2. Add passphrase to keyring

Paste the previously revealed passphrase

```
sudo ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek
Passphrase: 54b86496d376242f0bef16886a1a2218
Inserted auth tok with sig [aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa] into the user session keyring
Inserted auth tok with sig [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb] into the user session keyring
```

### 3. Mount

Replace the keys. Previously you need to create the target mount folder "plain" in /mnt (/mnt/plain)

```
sudo mount -i -t ecryptfs -o ecryptfs_sig=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16 /home/.ecryptfs/USER/.Private /mnt/plain
```

## And done! The files are in /mnt/plain.

25 hours of research and testing, to solve it with just a few lines.